# "You're reading this because..[reason]..aren't you."

Tags: word-usage

I came across an image of a toilet cleaning product, which had the following printed on the label:

> You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet didn't you

Forgiving the lack of punctuation, someone on the online forum pointed out that the correct format would be "aren't you", not "didn't you".

To me, both make sense, as you could be referring to the first part of the sentence ("you're reading"), or the middle part ("you forgot").
Could they both be appropriate?

Answer (score 16):

Here are the two versions, numbered for convenience and with sentence-punctuation disregarded:

1. You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet didn't you
2. You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet aren't you

In sentence 2, *aren't you* matches *you're reading*, which we can write as *you **are** reading*. There's no disagreement with this form, so let's focus on sentence 1.

In sentence 1, *didn't you* matches *you forgot*, which we can write as *you **did** forget*. (It could conceivably match *you went* as well, but that just compounds the problem.) So the structure of sentence 1 may be thought of as

- You're reading this because (reason)

However, "*you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet didn't you*" is a rhetorical question, not really a reason. So if we punctuate #1 in the straightforward manner, it's not grammatically correct:

- (*) You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet, didn't you?

If we punctuate it differently, however, we can argue that the sentence employs anacoluthon:

- You're reading this because ... you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet, didn't you?

> An anacoluthon is an unexpected discontinuity in the expression of ideas within a sentence, leading to a form of words in which there is logical incoherence of thought. Anacolutha are often sentences interrupted midway, where there is a change in the syntactical structure of the sentence and of intended meaning following the interruption. An example is the Italian proverb "The good stuff – think about it."
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluthon)

You ask:

> Could they both be appropriate?

Yes, they *could*, but only if the missing punctuation is filled in appropriately.

Comment: It's a written question on a bottle with no way to reply. Isn't it safe to say it is a rhetorical question?

Comment: If we place the missing punctuation in the straightforward manner, the sentence as a whole *isn't* a rhetorical question. The *embedded* rhetorical question is then out of place.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, and a word I'd never heard before.

Comment: @LevP You're welcome. Yes, it doesn't come up in conversation much. These days, it's often enough to know the concepts, and rely on web searches for the technical terms.

Comment: This is going to be like whacking a bee hive, but I've got to say it. This is not an example of anacoluthon. It's just employing an insufficient definition to mould this sentence to it.

Comment: @Ash I was referring to the interrupted flow after the word because, when the sentence is conveniently punctuated. That interrupted flow sounds like anacoluthon to me.

Answer (score 10):

> 1. "You forgot your smartphone when you went to the bathroom, didn't you?"

The focus of the sentence is your forgetting the phone.

> 2. "You're reading this, aren't you?"

The focus of the sentence is that you are reading it.

"Because" is used as a conjunction, and the second half of the conjunction is akin to example 1. The two sentences could be divided without the conjunction as follows:

You're reading this. You forgot your smart phone when you went to the bathroom, didn't you?

Answer (score 4):

Just answering because I feel there are some incomplete and some inaccurate answers.

> You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet, didn't you?

is incorrect because the primary statement here is `You are reading....` not `You forgot...`

> You forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet, didn't you?

is correct because the primary statement here is `You forgot....`

> You're reading this because you forgot your smartphone when you went to the toilet, aren't you?

is correct and what you require in this case because the primary statement here is `You are reading...`. I don't believe both the usages you suggested are appropriate.